# How can I set a variable a value based on the value of another variable in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am having a variable in terraform in vars.tf

```
var "isadd1DiskSourceExists"
{
  description="Additional Disk Source"
  default="false"
}
```

I am having another variable in terraform:

```
variable "add_source_image" {
  description = "Source image value."
  default     = ""
}
```

I like to assign the following value to add_source_image in a locals block
locals {

```
add_source_image = var.add_source_image != "" ? var.add_source_image : "centos-7-v20201112"):""
```

}

but I would like this **add_source_image** to be assigned any value only if
**isadd1DiskSourceExists** exists

like

```
locals {

    if var.isadd1DiskSourceExists // only if true
        add_source_image = var.add_source_image != "" ? var.add_source_image : "centos-7-v20201112"):""

}
```

How to achieve this in terraform?

Comment: Is this not equivalent to `var.add_source_image != "" && var.isadd1DiskSourceExists`?

Comment: var.add_source_image != "" && var.isadd1DiskSourceExists? var.add_source_image : "centos-7-v20201112" @MattSchuchard is this correct?

Comment: very new to terraform so I am not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary and the [coalesce function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/coalesce) to combine these conditionals in your `locals`:

```
locals {
  add_source_image = var.isadd1DiskSourceExists ? coalesce(var.add_source_image, "centos-7-v20201112") : ""
}
```

Comment: Thank You, is there any editor in terraform where i can practice these commands, I am finding no editor online and this one looks like closed: https://www.katacoda.com/courses/terraform/playground

Comment: @user1403505 https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/console should be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, i was using that, but i am not sure how to use it, as a simple expression is failing  in terraform console                                                                                          >variable “additional_disks” { default=[{disk_name="disk-0",disk_size_gb=10,device_name="disk-0",disk_type="pd-standard"}]}             
  │ Error: Invalid character   on <console-input> line 1:   (source code not available)  "Curly quotes" are not valid here
│ help to replace the character with a "straight quote".